# Ansible prompt and check_mode

Tags: ansible

I have a "vars_prompt" setup for the "check_mode" option:

```
---
 - name: Test check_mode from prompt
   hosts: localhost

   vars_prompt:
   - name: "check_mode"
     prompt: "Check mode: yes(default)=check-only, no=execute commands"
     private: no
     default: true

   tasks:
   - name: msg="False test | {{ check_mode }}"
     debug: var=check_mode
     when: not check_mode

   - name: msg="True test | {{ check_mode }}"
     debug: var=check_mode
     when: check_mode
```

When I run the playbook (`ansible-playbook -i myhosts test.yml`) and answer `true` or `false` the tests work as expected, but when I use "yes" and "no" (as the http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_checkmode.html document mentions), I get this error:

```
The conditional check 'check_mode' failed. The error  was: error
while evaluating conditional (check_mode): 'no' is undefined
```

Is this an error in the document, or in how I'm using the `check_mode` variable in the `when` clause?  It was my impression that true/yes and false/no were automagically handled.

Answer (score 0):

After working with Ansible for the past six months I came across my own question again, but this time I have my own answer.

The problem is that "yes" and "no" strings are not automatically converted to boolean values of true/false by Ansible.  To force the conversion use the "|bool" filter like this:

```
tasks:
- debug: msg="False test | {{ check_mode }}"
  when: not check_mode|bool

- debug: msg="True test | {{ check_mode }}"
  when: check_mode|bool
```

Comment: To be more specific: `yes/no` and others (`y|Y|yes|Yes|YES|n|N|no|No|NO|true|True|TRUE|false|False|FALSE|on|On|ON|off|Off|OFF`) are "converted" by YAML processor.

Comment: @dan_linder unfortunately this technique forces you to pollute the code with `|bool` everywhere since the underlying variable `check_mode` is not of type bool.

Answer (score 0):

Since Ansible 2.1, there is a new variable `ansible_check_mode` of type bool. The [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_checkmode.html#information-about-check-mode-in-variables) show this example :

```
tasks:

  - name: this task will be skipped in check mode
    git: repo=ssh://git@github.com/mylogin/hello.git dest=/home/mylogin/hello
    when: not ansible_check_mode

  - name: this task will ignore errors in check mode
    git: repo=ssh://git@github.com/mylogin/hello.git dest=/home/mylogin/hello
    ignore_errors: "{{ ansible_check_mode }}"
```